# Obtaining ADSB Mode-S Data Feeds for Aircraft from the FAA

Tags: data-request, real-time, aviation

A number of sites are publishing ADS-B/Mode-S data on maps, obtained from the FAA with a 5 minute delay.

We would like to get access to these feeds, but I cannot find who to contact or where to start. The FAA web site has turned up with information about the programs but no way to access the real time data.

http://www.data.gov/developers/page/developer-resources also does not list it.

Can anyone tell me who to contact to obtain this real time data?

Comment: How do you know that the sites are getting the data from the FAA? It would help to provide links to these sites.

Comment: That data is collected by the FAA through its NextGen ground stations. It has to be sourced from the FAA. Thats why the question. A number of sites simply state "FAA data with 5 minute delay".

Comment: I think these sites are using the ASDI data stream. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Situation_Display_to_Industry Could you link to a site that you think is using ADS-B data from the FAA?

Comment: @fgregg Have a look at [FlightRadar24](http://flightradar24.com). The Orange aircraft are annotated as 5 min delay from the FAA. Thanks

Comment: Right. So on that site's page it says it gets data from two sources. The first source of data is a network of ADB-S recievers. The second source is the FAA, that FAA data source is almost certainly ASDI.

Comment: Thanks @fgregg. If you would care to give me an answer, I will be happy to vote it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAA does not seem to provide a stream of ADB-S data, but does provide a stream of about airplane location and disposition called [Aircraft Situation Display to Industry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_Situation_Display_to_Industry). Getting access to this stream is not completely straightforward, but you can start with the [FAA's page on the program](http://www.fly.faa.gov/ASDI/asdi.html).

Answer (score 3):

Although the FAA does not redistribute ADS-B data, FlightAware (the largest aggregator and provider of this data) does offer worldwide ADS-B data feeds in a variety of formats: https://flightaware.com/commercial/data/adsb/

Answer (score 3):

ADS-B Exchange offers free licenses for personal/non-profit use:
[ADS-B Exchange Data/APIs](http://www.adsbexchange.com/data)

Answer (score 2):

[FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/) and [Harris Caprock](http://www.harriscaprock.com/) have this data.  FlightAware has an [API](https://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/) that is easy to use. You are going to have to pay for real time data.

Answer (score 2):

You can decode ads-b, FM radio, pager traffic, and various other signals (most anything in the 50MHz -2200 MHz range)  with a 9 dollar european TV USB antenna if it has the rtl2832U chipset. Google rtlsdr or rtlsdr ads-b.

Answer (score 2):

You may exchange with [www.adsbhub.org](http://www.adsbhub.org) , they provide unfiltered ADS-B data and support several protocols