# Free, real-time, aviation data API

Tags: data-request, uk, aviation

Similar to my question [Free source of AIS data (API)](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/15329/free-source-of-ais-data-api/15354), but for aviation.

I am looking for a free, real-time, API for positions of aircraft. Ideally near London City airport, failing that, UK airports; as a fall back, anything at all, as long as it is real-time. The more info about the flight that is available, the better.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1054/1511 ??

Comment: Great link, thanks. Although it seems to address only North America (via the FAA), it has some good looking links in it. I will investigate further and post here what I find. Thanks again (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best that I have found so far is https://opensky-network.org/   It even offers antonymous access to data, but why not join? The REST API is at https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html

---

---

https://www.adsbexchange.com/data/# offers free for non-commercial use data. However, it requires you to set up alive feed of your own data, to share it with others.

There is also https://uk.flightaware.com/commercial/firehose/, which also requires payments

Ditto, https://uk.flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/

http://www.adsbhub.org/ is another that requires you to share your data to obtain access.

As mentioned above, I have a similar interest in maritime data (AIS). It looks like my solution to my question [Seeking the cheapest possible AIS receiver](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11225/seeking-the-cheapest-possible-ais-receiver) costing $60 / Eur 55 / £50 will allow me to share data and, thus, access that of others.

A similar device (an ADS-B receiver) for aviation costs from about $18 / Eur 16.50 / £ 15, and that's just a quick glance; no doubt Ali Express & BangGood will be cheaper.

[These](https://uk.flightaware.com/adsb/prostick/) look excellent !! They get good reviews [here](https://thepihut.com/products/flightaware-pro-stick-plus-usb-sdr-ads-b-receiver#). In fact, even though I can get free data without any hardware., these are so cheap that I will get one, just to play around with it.

You get what you pay for, of course, but I live only 2 miles from a major river and a major airport, which should be good enough for proof of concept. Plus, of course, even a minimal data stream should be enough to show willing and allow you share the data of others with better rigs.

Once I figure out how to set up the receivers and sign up to the APIs, I will update my answers to all related questions.