# Searching downloadable ADS-B database

Tags: data-request, historical, database, aviation

I'm looking for a downloadable ADS-B historical database preferably with a free option, like the one that [OpenSky-Network](https://opensky-network.org/data/impala) offers. To my knowledge, unfortunately, the OpenSky-Network database doesn't provide ADS B data that complied with DO-260B, where the quality indicators (the **NUC** (Navigation Uncertainty Code) or **NACp** (Navigation Accuracy Code for Position) or **NIC** (Navigation Integrity Code) or **SIL** (Surveillance Integrity Level)) are also included.

Any suggestions on other websites that offer downloadable ADS-B historical databases that include the quality indicators?

Comment: Have u tried here https://www.adsbexchange.com/data/#

Comment: Based on what I read on https://www.adsbexchange.com/datafields/  the website didn't offer quality indicators value.

Comment: I think this is duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1054/1511

Answer (score 0):

There is likely none, any of the websites that offer ADS-B data are fairly easy to find, too trivial to list them here even. If none of the half dozen or so offer what you need (in particular for free), you might have to collect your own data or engage as a volunteer with one of them. I'm sure your work would be appreciated!

That said, have you tried decoding it yourself from the available raw messages in OpenSky? Sounds like it might work from:
https://github.com/junzis/pymodes-opensky
https://mode-s.org/decode/adsb/uncertainty.html